# When engaging the brake lever: the cable loosens and doesn't stay in the other side (where the twisty bit is)

Tags: brakes, brake-levers

[image: theirs a little cylinder in there]

Picture inside. Bike newbie here, Tried adjusting v-brakes from rubbing but now when using the brakes this pivot piece pops out (instead of going back in). Why is this happening what are my options here? thanks!

The cylinder in there is not aligned, not sure if that matters? I tried to align it but it will not stay put (from wear?). Front brake is the same story.

Comment: Your mention of the "twisty bit" is confusing as the first thing I think of hearing that is the cable nut on the brake arm.

Comment: @whatsisname I think you're right - the inner-cable retaining bolt nut is not clamping properly and as the lever is pulled, its drawing extra inner through the retaining bolt.  Could be a poor design of V brake, or a damaged nut/bolthead, or a flattened or greased/oily cable not clamping properly.    Could try adjusting the inner cable better, and then clamping down the retaining bolt on the left-front brakearm.  Risk is stripping or stretching the bolt/socket.

Comment: @whatsisname Also, there's a fair chance of inner/outer cable corrosion causing the inner cable to not move back through smoothly.   Personally I'd do a cable replacement on bikes like that - a kit is relatively cheap from Wiggle, their "lifeline" brand.  And possibly a pad replacement too.

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me like you are pulling too much cable. It even looks like your brake lever is close to being able to bottom out against your levers. In normal operation, brake levers do not come out nearly as much as you have as in the picture.

First thing to check is to make sure your brake pads are not worn out. If they are, replace them. Then re-adjust your brakes so that you have as little clearance as possible without any rim rubbing. If your wheels are so out of true that doing so is very difficult, it would be worth resolving that.

Then, check your brake arm tensioning spring. This will help pull on the cable and to keep the cylindrical cable end seated in the slot on the brake lever. See if you can move the spring to a higher tension setting. Your frames brake post should have three holes in it, you can adjust the tension by removing the brake arm and replacing it with the spring in a different hole, and your brake arm may also have a tension adjustment screw to fine tune it.

And just as a sanity check, make sure the cable isn't slipping through the cable binding bolt when you hit the brakes.

Comment: Agreed - brakes are the one area you need to work right when you want them.  Its a good idea to get someone to check them over just to make sure they're correct.